# How to troubleshoot issues related to API Connect in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I'm leveraging API Connect service on Bluemix and keep facing following issue multiple times so wanted to know, where to go and troubleshoot these sort of issues quickly on Bluemix ? Please let me know if you need any additional details.

**Could not process the API request. See the server log for more information, or contact your administrator.
Error ID: 5851d7e30cf27aa48695c426**

In addition to this, since we don't have access to runtime component (DataPower) so how to troubleshoot runtime issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Bluemix docs? The [API Connect docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/index.html) include a troubleshooting section. There is also documentation on the [DataPower Connector](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/cldint_005.html#cldint_005).

Comment: As per my understanding, DataPower connector is used to connect API's running on bluemix with SOR's running on-prem behind the firewall. That too, I'm bit confused now. We're leveraging "Secure Gateway Service" on Bluemix and "Secure Gateway Client" object on DataPower appliance to expose our on-prem SOAP based services as REST API's. Do we need to use DataPower connector instead of Secure Gateway Service ?

Comment: And moreover, since we're running API's on bluemix and leveraging their Datapower service as runtime component so not sure how can I access that box to see logs ?

Comment: I went through troubleshooting section in [API Connect docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/troubleshoot/ts_index.html#ts_index) but that doesn't contain anything what I'm looking for. I'm looking to troubleshoot runtime issues. E.q. When I invoke the API, I do get back - 500 Unable to open URL.